# RSpec not loading routes when namespacing directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

For easier organization, I'd like to namespace a couple folders under my /spec directory.  So rather than /spec/requests, I'd like to use /spec/**another_directory**/requests.

However, when I run my specs under these new namespaced directories, I get

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `whatever_path'
```

So, it looks as those my routes are no longer being properly loaded.  If I move the file back up to spec/requests (without the namespace), all is well and the test is green.

Not really sure what the issue is.  I'm requiriing 'spec_helper' in my files.  I've also seen:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../spec_helper'
```

and its variations, but I'm not really sure how that helps because it seems to load the spec_helper, just not the routes.  And to further make things fun, I'm reloading the routes before each run in the Spork.pre_fork block

```
Spork.each_run do
  load "#{Rails.root}/config/routes.rb"
end
```

but I still get the error whether Spork is running or not.

What am I doing wrong?

(rspec-rails 2.8.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is due [request example before hook](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example/request_example_group.rb) is not fired. If you look [further](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/example.rb), you can understand how rspec-rails decide which example type it runs.

I suggest you to use `spec/requests/another_directory` schema or you can try to reconfigure Rspec somewhat like:

```
RSpec::configure do |config|
   config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, :type => :request,
        :example_group => {:file_path => 'path/to/your/requests')}
end
```

Comment: Thank you!. I accepted your answer as it lead to the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
config.include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup, :type => :request, 
  :example_group => { 
  :file_path => config.escaped_path(%w[spec (my|folder|names) requests])}
```

But, then it's not getting the Capybara methods, so I include then again after the above config block

```
config.include Capybara::DSL, :type => :request
config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, :type => :request
```

I wanted to make the path more elastic so I don't have to have include each 'parent' folder.  I tried using ** instead of having to include (each|folder), but it wasn't loading.  I then tried setting the path directly using:

```
:file_path => "spec/../requests"
```

but then I lose the ability to run a single file.

Either way, the above code works, just have to pipe each of your folder's names.